# Should I use a constructor when size is known

Tags: c++, performance, dynamic

Is there any different between these two implementation

```
//SIZE is known before runtime
class A{
   int* p1 = new int[SIZE];
}
class B{
   int* p1;
   B(){//Using constructor
   p1 = new int[SIZE];
   }
}
```

Comment: only bad if you make another constructor and forget to initialize p1.

Comment: If size is known before runtime you're better off with an array or a `std::array`. By dynamically allocating the class opens up [a whole can of worms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: and use a std::vector even with known size. You get free lifecycle management and bounds checking in debug mode on most compilers

Comment: @user4581301 `If size is known before runtime you're better off with an array or a std::array` Depends on the known size. If it's large, then such member would be problematic since creating automatic variables of the class could easily result in stack overflow. In such case dynamic array is better. It wouldn't open up a can of worms if RAII was used (such as `std::vector`).

Comment: That'll teach me to leave out `vector` to try and keep the comment short.

Comment: Note: `p1 = new int[SIZE];` is an assignment while `int* p1 = new int[SIZE];` is an initialization. There's no real difference for a pointer, but for an object with non-trivial initialization logic, a default initialization followed by an assignment could be costly.

Comment: `B` is telling you that you are forgetting not only a `delete`, but also a `~B`.

Comment: If  the size is known, then why is allocation with `new` necessary at all?

Answer (score 0):

There is no practical difference between these two examples.

P.S. Avoid owning bare pointers. Simplest solution for safe use of dynamic arrays is `std::vector`.

P.P.S. Prefer using member initialisers (either a default member initialiser such as in the second example, or in the member initialisation list) to assigning uninitialised members when possible.